# Java:Collection-How to create a multiple columns

Tags: java, collections

I am Want to Store multiple Students information in Collection like,
Name,Age ,Sex,...
So which is best Collection should i create to store the information.

If there is any other alternative Solution PLz inform me... THX

Comment: You may use Set or List or Map based on your requirments

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275669/java-collections-collection-for-an-employee-store

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a Student class like

```
class Student {
   String name;
   String age;
   String sex;
   etc....
}
```

And then create a collection like

```
Collection<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Then create student objects and add them to collection

```
Student student1 = new Student();
students.add(student1);
```

Answer (score 1):

On my experience for something like this is working good to use `ArrayList`. Just create a new `class Students` with his respective atributes and then store it in an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

or

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

You may can also have a look to the tutorial of Oracle about `ArrayList`: [ArrayList Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Greets

Answer (score 1):

Totally depends on your requirement. Requirements like:-

1. Do you want to store any information that is going to be unique for each     student for eg RollNo.
2. Do you want your information to be ordered or not.

In order to choose any collection your requirement must be clear.

Which Collection to choose?

- Insertion and deletion is faster in LinkedList but when it comes to searching ArrayList is more fast. You can sort this data by using Utility class Collections.sort(yourList);
- If you want to avoid duplicate entry then go for HashSet or LinkedHashSet. HashSet is unordered while LinkedHashSet is ordered.
- If you want Students set of data to be sorted then go for TreeSet.
- If you have unique record like RollNo and you want that information of students should be mapped with RollNo then you can go for HashMap and LinkedHashMap with the latter being the ordered one.
- If you want the keys to be sorted then go for TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use List of Map.
Check this example:

```
List<Map<String , String>> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String , String> studentRecord = new HashMap();
//Record for first Student
studentRecord.put("Name","Value1");
studentRecord.put("Age","Value2");
studentRecord.put("Sex","Value3");
studentList.add(studentRecord);
//Record for second Student
studentRecord.put("Name","Value1");
studentRecord.put("Age","Value2");
studentRecord.put("Sex","Value3");
studentList.add(studentRecord);
```